# Set each system as data node and get the data from each

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm very beginner if the hadoop and HDFS

- There is 5 servers connected in lan
- Each server has log files with different data

Problems is this

- I need to process all the log files with Spark.
- I need to load all the log files to spark and process.
- I had a idea to have hdfs cluster, like each servers as slave (Each
  one as slave)  and request to each slave and get the log files and
  load to spark.

Am I correct or is there any better way or better technology.

Comment: Big Data technologies are all about the Cluster

Comment: Yes but in my requirement the each node has different data. Every time I need to combine all log files from each server and process to get the output

Comment: What about mesos with Spark ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say there are 100 log files and each node has 20 of them in **local file system**. And your question is should I load all 100 to spark?

Before running spark you need to load the files **from local file system into HDFS** (If the files are in different nodes you can load them using SSH or something). Then, execute your spark program specifying the HDFS location of the 100 log files.

Typical scenario as steps:
Assuming there are 100 log files in 5 servers (20 each) and 5 servers are a hadoop cluster:

Step 1 : Load the files into HDFS. Propagate hdfs load command from all 5 servers. At this point, you should have all 100 files when you try **hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/logfiles**

Step 2 : Execute Spark program point to this /path/to/logfiles location.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is the actual scenario.  Assume there are 5 remote servers all five servers have log files, example all log files contain product ids,  same product id can be exist in another node's log , My job is to get total unique product id from all servers's log

Comment: @Muhunthan - I have updated my answer based on your comment. Please check.

Comment: Let me know if you need more input. Kindly tick over if you accept my answer

Comment: Okay sure, Sadly this is new account and I don't have enough reputation, I'll do once I get it